# For some reasons one of my users is seeing all numbers replaced with asterisk "*", why is that?

Tags: fonts

For some reasons one of my users is seeing all numbers replaced with asterisk "*", why is that?

I can't provide the website url. The user is using mozilla. I put a custom font roboto.

Noticed the email is also hidden. Or maybe is cloudflare?

I have the screenshots from hotjar

Maybe is a virus on the user's pc?

Comment: Is it only happening in Mozilla? That would be the first question I'd ask them. Without seeing the source it's hard to say, I've never come across this myself. Is it in form inputs or in the actual page markup?

How is the font stack being written in the css? Are you linking to Roboto OK or assuming the user has it locally?

Comment: Found out that hotjar actually hides all numbers and emails. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hotjar does that automatically. See how to fix it here: https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012439167-Suppressing-Content-in-Recordings